# Cannot install rpm package on Ubuntu 11.10 -- needs libc.so.6

Tags: glib

I am trying to install an odbc driver for vPostgres (Vmware's version for postgres) on Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit).
I have downloaded the rpm file of the installer (64-bit) and when I try to install the rpm using:

rpm -ivh Vmware-vPostgres-client.rpm,   it shows me this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libresolv.so.2()(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
    libresolv.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by VMware-vPostgres-client-1.0.1.1145-532311.x86_64
```

Few things I have tried:

locate libpthread.so.0 returns:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

/lib32/libpthread.so.0
```

I get similar locations for all other files:
locate libc.so.6

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

/lib32/libc.so.6
```

and so on.

I tried creating symlinks using:

```
sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 /lib64/libc.so.6

sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 /lib/libc.so.6

sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 libc.so.6
```

but none of them worked. I am not sure where exactly it is trying to search for this files.

ldd Vmware-vPostgres-client.rpm doesnt help much and returns 
'not a dynamic executable' which is expected

I tried adding the path in the /etc/ld.so.conf file

include  lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

I also tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the specified file but of no use.

ldd --version shows
GLIBC 2.13

Can anyone help me out where exactly does it searches for the file?

Comment: Try downloading a deb version of the file from vmware. rpm would normally require you to be using alien as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the package `alien` to convert it to a `deb` package and then use `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb` or GUI based GDebi Application Installer to install it. They should report you package-wise unmet dependencies.